# Yii2 Difference of when and whenClient

Tags: php, yii2

```
['size', 'required','when' => function($model) {
        return ($model->color == 'RED') ? true : false;
    },
    'whenClient' => "function() {
        if($('#provider').val() == 'RED') {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }"]
```

I wonder if I still need to put the `whenClient` code? My validation still working without submitting the form by using only `when`.

Comment: Refer to [manual](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/702/using-whenclient-for-complex-client-side-validation/) for this.

Comment: `whenClient` works on client side of validation only. BTW there are flaws in this short code. You need `color` field to be required but only when it's attribute value is `RED`? It makes no sense. And in `whenClient` function should return boolean value, typing just `true` or `false` without `return` does nothing.

Comment: @Bizley sorry for the above snippet, Im just wondering why does on may UI part, the `when` code run even though im not submitting the form. Is my understanding correct that `when` triggers only if form was submitted? thanks in advance

Comment: `when` part is for the server side validation. If client side validation is enabled `when` is ignored by client so in your case `required` rule is always applied client-side - that is why you need `whenClient`.